# Where to read about PSO (partial store order) memory model

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, concurrency, program-verification, program-analysis

I have been reading about TSO (total store order) memory models for concurrent programs, but I can not find resources for PSO (partial store order) memory models. Can someone please point to resources. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These explains better : [TSO and PSO Memory
Models](https://research-explorer.app.ist.ac.at/download/10191/10215/2021_ProcACMPL_Bui.pdf)
[Dynamic_Partial_Order_Reduction_for_Relaxed_Memory_Models](https://cpb-us-e1.wpmucdn.com/sites.usc.edu/dist/c/321/files/2019/03/ZhangKW15-2kridoi.pdf)

Also contains resources for further learning at the end.